# Can not access share from one of 3 domain controlers

Tags: networking, network-shares, windows-server

> Setup: 3 DC's in the Samen VLAN network.

DC1: Windows server 2016

DC2: Windows server 2019

DC3: Windows server 2019

> Problem:

All company data is op DC3 I have added myself with full control using the domain Administrators built in group.

When i try to reach the data on DC1 and DC2 trough \hostname\data --> works perfect.

When i try this on DC3 is does not work same whit the IP and localhost --> no access.

I tryed creating a new groups --> same result.

When i add myself directly (not using a group) it works.

I find it strange that this works on other servers but not on the DC3.

Comment: What does “op” stand for? Acronyms must be spelled out typically. Which server is the primary?

Comment: How can we answer that? We don't know the differences in setup between the DCs and nothing about your network architecture.

Comment: What is the specific error message you get? Please edit your question to add more details

Comment: @Ramhound, i read "op" as a mispelling of "on". at least that makes sense contextually (especially with the reference to localhost).